# Generate 10,000 random values in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have this Oracle table. For development purposes I want to generate 10,000 different values into the table. How I can do this?

```
CREATE TABLE ERRORLOG(
  ERRORID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ERRORCONTENT CLOB NOT NULL,
  ERRORDATE TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Into which column, or columns? If it's the CLOB, what kind of values - different lengths, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I want to insert in all three columns different values random generated.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for just something chaotic in CLOB (including length and content) you may use DBMS_RANDOM:

```
SQL> select DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('p',DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,30)) rand_str from dual connect by level <= 10
  2  /

RAND_STR                                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#<a                                                                             
tV&Og8=:f}Is/sR2L>F\7wCL)_V2                                                    
/WBp Y)V5ZD.v                                                                   
_yw(o_                                                                          
b:5&E}7\a1Gt]X}$}e*-W[6U=1                                                      
L<hQ:L^5}A(]<:}+8|-{.F%&`L                                                      
G!L'Rbgiw/o]r~`[@9d6FUi3dc7                                                     
.h_y;yeh`*rUK+\~8^i<G+;L76*                                                     
ec}aL                                                                           
d3)UFT)S2kDA5
```

And the same package can be used to generate values in other columns (but I suppose ERRORID is a primary key, so you can use any other method which guarantess uniqueness - like sequence).

```
SQL> create sequence seq_x;

SQL> select x_seq.nextval, DBMS_RANDOM.STRING('p',DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,30)) rand_str,
systimestamp + numtodsinterval(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,40),'MINUTE') rand_ts 
from dual connect by level <= 10;

   NEXTVAL RAND_STR                        RAND_TS                               
---------- ------------------------------  -----------------------------------   
         1 a?=PK7yA|L8]d/)3!               24.03.14 19:47:18,750326032 +04:00    
         2 $N+K4vksVx(npxm^'#/%.Aay5$,     24.03.14 19:50:48,361699672 +04:00    
         3  },7(1iX,2'E@i3u;wdg?.BB        24.03.14 19:35:15,711777571 +04:00    
         4 :S8x vj!m!:YI% fLCy8$\Y_}C      24.03.14 19:43:41,088255060 +04:00    
         5 /'oFj@+jOv3uFZC\z;^2+9GG~       24.03.14 19:59:02,214021766 +04:00    
         6 8vTh0}[HYBEDy{4\                24.03.14 20:06:34,600594460 +04:00    
         37 >u w9q)]c7/hB_butzNR\Oi!hWwO<& 24.03.14 19:36:39,010531153 +04:00    
         8 >GwzDBT8!?g}(<8;@I              24.03.14 19:51:52,118620451 +04:00    
         9 -] 'NxHUx46"_(df"8.u:6Pel"      24.03.14 19:44:04,152845952 +04:00    
        10 "HAJ                            24.03.14 20:00:24,933479299 +04:00
```

Comment: How I can generate 10 000 rows for random values into my table?

Comment: INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM dual connect by level <= 10000  should work to you.

Comment: @PeterPenzov - worth noting though that `dbms_random.string` returns a `varchar2`; which you can of course put into a `clob` column, but you're limited in the size it can produce, so if you actually need data > 4k (from SQL) or > 32k (from PL/SQL) you'll need to build up a temporary `clob` by appending random strings. Or copy an existing value from somewhere else, if you have one big enough.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to generate data is by using other database applications like TOAD.
check the bellow pic.
[image]